# Check_path isn't behind symfony's firewall , how to correct this?

Tags: security, authentication, symfony

I am trying to authenticate against symfony2 firewall , here is my security config

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    providers:
        in_memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: user, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ]}
        #main:
            #entity: { class: Surgeworks\CoreBundle\Entity\User, property: username}
    firewalls:
        public:
           pattern: .*
           security: false
           anonymous: true
           form_login:
                check_path: /{_locale}/admin/logincheck
        login:
           pattern: ^/{_locale}/admin/login$
           security: false
           anonymous:  ~
        dev:
           pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           security: false
           anonymous:  ~
        secured_area :
            provider:   in_memory
            pattern: ^/{_locale}/admin/.*
            form_login:
                check_path: /{_locale}/admin/logincheck
                login_path: /{_locale}/admin/login
            logout:
                path : /{_locale}/admin/logout
                target : /{_locale}/admin/
            remember_me:
               key:      aSecretKey
               lifetime: 3600
               path:     /admin/
               domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER 
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/{_locale}/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/{_locale}/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ar/admin/logincheck, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/(ar|en|fr)/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

and here is my routing  in `DaghoSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`:

```
_admin:
    pattern: /admin/
    defaults: { _controller: DaghoSiteBundle:Login:login , _locale : ar }
    requirements:
     _locale: (ar|en|fr)
login:
    pattern: /admin/login
    defaults : { _controller: DaghoSiteBundle:Login:login , _locale : ar }
    requirements:
        _locale: (ar|en|fr)
logincheck:
    pattern: /admin/logincheck
    #defaults: { _controller: DaghoSiteBundle:Login:logincheck , _locale: ar }
    #requirements:
        #_locale: (ar|en|fr)
logout:
    pattern: /admin/logout
```

I can't login through these setting ,
it always throw an exception

> Unable to find the controller for path "/ar/admin/logincheck". Maybe
>   you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration

and even if had setup the route `check_path` page >>  i would be able to  view the `check_path` without  being redirected to login page ..

```
/en/admin >> login page 
/en/logincheck >> display the logincheck template (i.e  /en/logincheck isn't behind firewall )
```

how to fix , or debug this issue , please advise

UPDATE:
sorry  I  might forget to write that i had prefixed my bundle with the `{_locale}`  like this 
in my routing.yml

```
DaghoSiteBundle:
    resource: "@DaghoSiteBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: ar|en|fr
    defaults: { _locale: ar }
```

Comment: as `pattern` accept regx, you can not use {placeholder} inside it

Answer (score 2):

I think you must change your route patterns to include your `_locale` parameter. Instead of, for example, `pattern: /admin/logincheck` you should use `pattern: {_locale}/admin/logincheck`

You can also debug your routes by using a console command `app/console router:debug`.

I am not 100% sure this fixes your problem, but I hope it helps you gather more info about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try

```
logincheck:
    pattern: /admin/login_check
    #defaults: { _controller: DaghoSiteBundle:Login:logincheck , _locale: ar }
    #requirements:
        #_locale: (ar|en|fr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, but my situation is simple and doesn't have the {_locale} functionality, but maybe it will help you anyway.

From the Security chapter of the Symf2 Book:
Common Pitfalls #3: **Be sure /login_check is behind a firewall.**

In your security.yml file it looks like your check_path route is /{_locale}/admin/logincheck, and your secured path is anything that's behind ^/{_locale}/admin/.*
so that seems to be good.
**You might want to try removing the .* (do you really need it?)**

and further down the file in the access control section you provide a specific entry to make sure the check_path requires authentication:
- { path: ^/ar/admin/logincheck, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
**Maybe try specifying this instead:

- { path: ^/{_locale}/admin/logincheck, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }**

But actually, I was wondering, **can you even use {placeholders} in the security.yml pattern values?** I know you can in the routing file, but I'm not sure if the security yml works the same way? I don't see it being used in any examples in the main symf2 book in the security or routing chapters?